# 2 arrays changing instead of 1

Tags: javascript

I am making a game with 2 arrays but one array changes when I don't want it to. Example from the console in browser:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7,8,9,10]
A=B
A.push(11)
A =[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
B =[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

the A is fine but is there a way to make the B stay `[6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: `A=B` doesn't create a copy. It causes `A` to be a reference to the same memory location; meaning when you change `A`, `B` changes, too, because it's the same object.

Comment: If it's not a Primitive value then assignment makes the var exactly the non-Primitive var. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Comment: A doesn't own `[1,2,3,4,5]`, it only points to `[1,2,3,4,5]` and so `A=B` makes B points to same array by sharing same reference

Comment: If you take a `.slice()` of the Array you want to copy, but not affect the original, that usually does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Use spread syntax as `A=[...B];` to copy `B` to `A`. As when you do `A=B` you are actually setting the reference of `B` to `A` so any changes to `A` result in changes in `B` and vice-versa.

```js
var A=[1,2,3,4,5];
var B=[6,7,8,9,10];
A=[...B];
A.push(11);
console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
A=B
```

you're making `A` refer to the *same array* that `B` points to. So naturally you see any change you make to that array regardless of which variable you use to look at the array they both refer to.

> the A is fine but is there a way to make the B stay [6,7,8,9,10]

It sounds like you want to *copy* the contents of `B` to `A`. To do that, you can use `slice`:

```
A = B.slice();
```

Alternately, in modern environments, you can use ES2015's spread notation [as Ankit pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810441/157247).

There's no need to assign anything to `A` initially, since you never use it.

Example:

```js
var A;
var B = [6,7,8,9,10];
A = B.slice();
A.push(11)
console.log(A); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
console.log(B); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7,8,9,10]
```

Here are three methods to copy an array into other

```
 A = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(B));
```

or

```
A = [].concat(B);
```

or

```
A= [...B];       //for ES6

A.push(11);    



/* 
A =[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
B =[6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

By `A=B`, you are assigning the variable `A` the same reference of `B` which means any change in either of the variable will be reflected in the other too as they both share same reference.

You can use **Spread Operator** in order to create a copy of the array

```js
let A = [1,2,3,4,5], B = [6,7,8,9,10];
A=[...B];
A.push(11);
console.log(A); // [6,7,8,9,10, 11]
console.log(B); // [6,7,8,9,10]
```

**Catch**

Please note, if the values are objects, then the objects will still continue to share the same reference.

```js
let A = [{x: 1}], B = [{y:2}];
A = [...B];
A.push({z:3});
A[0].y = 3;
console.log(A); // [{y:3}, {z:3}]
console.log(B); // [{y:3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Read my comments above. Then:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
a = b.slice(); a.push(11);
console.log('a', a); console.log('b', b);
```

Answer (score 0):

By assigning `A=B`, both variables point to the same array, and thus modifying it through one will be visible via the other. If you want `A` and `B` to refer to two different arrays, you could copy it instead of just assigning. E.g.:

```
B = A.slice(0);
```